# Key Value Observing in Java

Tags: java, key-value-observing

in Objective C one can make use of key value observing to get notifications of changes to objects & then the program can act accordingly; is there something similar in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look into PropertyChangeListener, which has been part of Java since JDK 1.0:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible in Java without implementing it yourself, so i wrote a little "library".

https://github.com/Appyx/JKVO

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but you can check the following library

https://github.com/ahmed-basyouni/AndroidKVO